# Serialization problems: objects that depend on each other and ArrayLists

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I have to serialize a project and it's the first time I use serialization. After getting informed about it, I thought of two possible problems: my classes have atributes which type is another different class that has atributes which type is the first class (explained poorly, but can see in the code) and the fact that I use ArrayLists (which I've read can't be serialized). So I decided to try with a very simplified version of the project:

A group, this containts an ArrayList of Person:

```
public class Group implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Person leader;
private List<Person> members;
private int number;

public Group(Person leader, int number) {
    this.leader = leader;
    this.number = number;
    this.members = new ArrayList<Person>();
    this.members.add(leader);
}

public void addMember(Person p) {
    this.members.add(p);
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
}
```

A person, this contains an ArrayList of Groups:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Group> groups;
private String name;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
}

public Group createGroup(int number) {
    Group g = new Group(this, number);
    this.groups.add(g);
    return g;
}

public void joinGroup(Group g) {
    this.groups.add(g);
    g.addMember(this);
}
}
```

And a main method which creates a few groups and people and uses writeObject() to write them into a file, plus another main that uses readObject() to get the objects back (it only uses readObject() and prints them).

I didn't expect this to work for the reasons mentioned above, but it worked perfectly, so I tried to serialize my main project (way more complex) but it didn't work (huge stack trace, simply saying "User", which is the equivalent to person, is not serializable).

Is there any reason for this or any major flaw that I should take into account?

I apologize for not including the two main methods I use, as well as none of the stacktrace or the main project, but I didn't want to make this question extremely long.

Comment: I am not sure which books you are reading; but when you check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html you will find that ArrayList can be serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my classes have atributes which type is another different class that has atributes which type is the first class (explained poorly, but can see in the code)

Incomprehensible. Both Java and Serialization handle circular dependencies, if that's what you're talking about.

> and the fact that I use ArrayLists (which I've read can't be serialized)

Wrong.

> simply saying "User", which is the equivalent to person, is not serializable

So `User` doesn't implement `Serializable.`

> Is there any reason for this or any major flaw that I should take into account?

Make `User` implement `Serializable.`Same for any other class that gives you the same message.

You need to read the [Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) and the relevant Javadoc, and stop relying on arbitrary Internet rubbish.

Comment: It was actually one of the atributes of User that didn't implement Serializable. I had read the Serializable interface doc but being the first thing I read about serialization I didn't get much out of it. I should've read it again later.